# How can I sign in with the Google SignIn SDK in a sharing extension?

Tags: ios, google-signin, ios8-extension

I have successfully signed in using the Google Sign-In SDK for iOS in my main app. However when I call `hasAuthIKeyChain()` from my sharing extension, it always returns `false`. Ideally, once the user has authenticated in the main app, I would like to call `signInSilently()` in my sharing extension to use the cached credentials.

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27082068/google-plus-sign-in-for-xcode-share-extension/27117092) about using the Google+ Sign-In SDK, I enabled keychain sharing for both my app and my sharing extension, and set the same keychain group for both. Unfortunately, this didn't help. One difference is that I don't see an option to specify the keychain name to use with the Google Sign-In SDK, though.

What do I need to do in order to share Google Sign-In credentials between my main app and my sharing extension?

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Comment: @sahara108 No unfortunately I haven't. Granted I haven't researched this recently either.

Comment: This can possibly be a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27082068/3655437

Comment: I also answered a similar question showing the steps to go through when implementing this http://stackoverflow.com/a/39295203/3655437